# What is the best way to concurrent formatting 1000 disks under centos

Tags: linux, automation, format, disk, systemmanagement

I've done this work with an expect script which seems working. But I think it must be a more elegant way to do things like this (is Puppet suitable for this job?). So I searched on Google, get nothing. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE：** I have 100 machines with 10 disks each. By formatting I mean to creating file systems with or without partitioning.

Comment: 1000 disks in one machine or 1000 machines with a single disk each?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "formatting"? creating partitions? creating file systems? or what?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any expect scripts. There are CLI tools perfectly usable from plain shell or Perl/Python scripts, that don't need any terminal interaction.
For partitioning, you can use `sfdisk`, for making file systems, you can use the appropriate `mkfs.xxx`. You can get the current partitioning scheme from `sfdisk -d` in a wonderful, easy-to-parse format, you can decide whether you want a different partitioning or not, then use `sfdisk` again to load the new partitioning scheme. `mkfs.xxx` binaries are also ready to be used from scripts, when used with the proper command-line options.

To handle multiple disks in parallel, I suggest to implement a script for a single disk, and run as many scripts in parallel as needed.